# Can somebody explain these entries in my sudoers file?

Tags: mac, security

What is going on in my `sudoers` file? I have no idea who the

```
FULLTIMERS = millert, mikef, dowdy
```

are or what these IP addresses

```
Host_Alias CUNETS = 128.138.0.0/255.255.0.0
Host_Alias CSNETS = 128.138.243.0, 128.138.204.0/24, 128.138.242.0
```

are? Has somebody tampered with the file?

PS: Full file below

```
#
# Sample /etc/sudoers file.
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# See the sudoers man page for the details on how to write a sudoers file.

##
# Override built-in defaults
##
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    env_keep += "BLOCKSIZE"
Defaults    env_keep += "COLORFGBG COLORTERM"
Defaults    env_keep += "__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING"
Defaults    env_keep += "CHARSET LANG LANGUAGE LC_ALL LC_COLLATE LC_CTYPE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_MESSAGES LC_MONETARY LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME"
Defaults    env_keep += "LINES COLUMNS"
Defaults    env_keep += "LSCOLORS"
Defaults    env_keep += "SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
Defaults    env_keep += "TZ"
Defaults    env_keep += "DISPLAY XAUTHORIZATION XAUTHORITY"
Defaults    env_keep += "EDITOR VISUAL"
Defaults    env_keep += "HOME MAIL"

Defaults    lecture_file = "/etc/sudo_lecture"

##
# User alias specification
##
# User_Alias    FULLTIMERS = millert, mikef, dowdy

##
# Runas alias specification
##
# Runas_Alias   OP = root, operator

##
# Host alias specification
##
# Host_Alias    CUNETS = 128.138.0.0/255.255.0.0
# Host_Alias    CSNETS = 128.138.243.0, 128.138.204.0/24, 128.138.242.0
# Host_Alias    SERVERS = master, mail, www, ns
# Host_Alias    CDROM = orion, perseus, hercules

##
# Cmnd alias specification
##
# Cmnd_Alias    PAGERS = /usr/bin/more, /usr/bin/pg, /usr/bin/less

##
# User specification
##

# root and users in group wheel can run anything on any machine as any user
root        ALL = (ALL) ALL
%admin      ALL = (ALL) ALL

## Read drop-in files from /private/etc/sudoers.d
## (the '#' here does not indicate a comment)
#includedir /private/etc/sudoers.d
```

Comment: Nothing you posted shows what was hacked, who hacked you, or what you've done to identify this is actually a problem.  Please edit your question and provide details so we can assist.

Comment: If you have been hacked, reinstall _all_ affected machines.

Comment: As far as I can tell, that's the default sudoers file on macOS?  (i.e. `/private/etc/sudoers~orig`).  Nothing there to suggest you've been hacked.

Comment: The lines with "fulltimers" is commented out because this appears to be a sample sudoers file.  In any event, it's not getting loaded.  If you were being hacked, it's by the most inept hackers on the planet.

Comment: @Alex - When referencing man pages, it's best to use the one that came with macOS by issuing the command `man sudo` or referencing it from a macOS man repository like https://ss64.com/osx/sudo.html  macOS ≠ Linux

Comment: If you need help in combining accounts, or getting access to the original account, please check the Contacts link at the bottom of the page. Editing the question is possible even if logged in as a different account though.

Answer (score 2):

This is the off-the-mill standard `sudoers` file which gets installed by default and contains some examples about potential configurations. Any line starting with `#` is a comment and doesn't enable anything. So at least from looking at the file you've included in the question it doesn't seem as if somebody has tampered with it.

Answer (score 2):

It says right at the top…

# Sample /etc/sudoers file.

The lines you expressed concern over are commented out with the # character and are only presented as examples so you can see the correct syntax to create your own entries.